# How to use GraphQL Fragments in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, graphql

Can anyone please help or direct me towards the reference,

how can we implement **GraphQL Fragments in Flutter**?

GraphQL Fragments Reference:
https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#fragments

Answer (score 1):

Artemis (Apollo's Sister ;) ) is the only viable GraphQL code generator that I have found to date. I've only gotten it working correctly with my schema on the latest beta version though.

https://pub.dev/packages/artemis

Comment: Thanks, I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement GraphQL fragments using **graphql_flutter** package as below.

```
mutation RegisterUser($input: UserInput!) {
  auth {
    register(input: $input) {
      ...RegisterSuccess
    }
  }
}

fragment RegisterSuccess on RegisterSuccess {
  userId
}
```

You can also make multiple fragments of the same **type** based on what you want to extract.

```
fragment User on User {
  id
  name
  email
  address
  phoneNumber
  emailVerified
  registeredDate
}

fragment BuyerInfo on User {
  id
  name
  email
  phoneNumber
}
```

For more detail checkout this article
[Flutter and GraphQL with Authentication](https://medium.com/@alishgiri/flutter-graphql-with-authentication-d3a2a82e979f).